# StructuredStreaming with ForEachWriter creating duplicates

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

Hi I'm trying to create a neo4j sink using pyspark and kafka, but for some reason this sink is creating duplicates in neo4j and I'm not sure why this is happening. I am expecting to get only one node, but it looks like it's creating 4. If someone has an idea, please let me know.

Kafka producer code:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='10.0.0.38:9092')
message = {
    'test_1': 'test_1',
    'test_2': 'test_2'
}

producer.send('test_topic', json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8'))
producer.close()
```

Kafka consumer code:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import findspark
from py2neo import Graph
import json

findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

class ForeachWriter:
    def open(self, partition_id, epoch_id):
        neo4j_uri = '' # neo4j uri
        neo4j_auth = ('', '') # neo4j user, password

        self.graph = Graph(neo4j_uri, auth=neo4j_auth)
        return True

    def process(self, msg):        
        msg = json.loads(msg.value.decode('utf-8'))
        self.graph.run("CREATE (n: MESSAGE_RECEIVED) SET n.key = '" + str(msg).replace("'", '"') + "'")

        raise KeyError('received message: {}. finished creating node'.format(msg))

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test-consumer') \
                            .config('spark.executor.instances', 1) \
                            .getOrCreate()        

ds1 = spark.readStream \
                   .format('kafka') \
                   .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', '10.0.0.38:9092') \
                   .option('subscribe', 'test_topic') \
                   .load()

query = ds1.writeStream.foreach(ForeachWriter()).start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

[neo4j graph after running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoNMf.png)

Answer (score 0):

After doing some searching, I found this snippet of text from *Stream Processing with Apache Spark: Mastering Structured Streaming and Spark Streaming* on chapter 11 p151 after describing open, process, and close for ForeachWriter:

> This contract is part of the data delivery semantics because it allows us to remove duplicated partitions that might already have been sent to the sink but are reprocessed by Structured Streaming as part of a recovery scenario. For that mechanism to properly work, the sink must implement some persistent way to remember the partition/version combinations that it has already seen.

On another note from the spark website: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html (see section on Foreach).

> Note: Spark does not guarantee same output for (partitionId, epochId), so deduplication cannot be achieved with (partitionId, epochId). e.g. source provides different number of partitions for some reasons, Spark optimization changes number of partitions, etc. See SPARK-28650 for more details. If you need deduplication on output, try out foreachBatch instead.

It seems like I need to implement a check for uniqueness because Structured Streaming automatically reprocesses partitions in case of a fail if I am to use ForeachWriter, otherwise I have to switch to foreachBatch instead.